# How do I toggle pixel grid in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

Ctrl+H toggles all the *extras*; it hides the guides/guide lines.
How do I toggle the pixel grid without toggling the guides altogether?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't relate to software development so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Please ask this question elsewhere, for example [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts and remap the View > Extras > Pixel Grid shortcut to toggle the pixel grid without toggling the guidelines altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl+H** (**Windows**) or **CMD+H** (**MAC**) hide the extras and may not be the ideal solution. Try to disable the pixel grid by clicking **View > Show > Pixel Grid**

[image]

Comment: How is that image relevant?